# Override usb or power cable connection sound in android device

Tags: android, android-intent, usb, broadcastreceiver, system-sounds

Is there any way to

> override the default sound that is made when an usb cable or power cable is connected to an android device ?

I am looking for a way to replace that **default system sound** with one of my own or even disable the sound completely.

I did some **digging** into the `android developer reference` and found that the intent `"android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"` can be used in a **broadcast receiver** to handle the power connected state of the device. But I cannot abort that broadcast (in case I do not want to play the default sound) as it is a non-ordered broadcast.

Is there any other way out around this ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I get a little sad when such valid questions pass by unnoticed.